# How to build a package with Setuptools and deploy to a private repo without leaking or hardcoding the password

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I am trying to build a Python package using Setuptools and deploy it to a private PyPI repository without leaking the repo password in the CI logs. I have access to the username and password for the repo in environment variables. For pushing the built package to the private repo I can do

```
python -m twine upload --username $USERNAME --password $PASSWORD --repository-url my-repo.com/pypi/ dist/*
```

I want something similar to configure the `easy_install` calls made by setuptools to fetch the `test_requires`. E.g. I would like to say

```
python setup.py test --username <username> --password <password> --repository-url my-repo.com/pypi/
```

After diving into the setuptools docs, the easy_install docs, and the distutils source code the best I have come up with is using `setopt` to add the repo URL to setup.cfg before running the tests like:

```
python setup.py setopt --command=easy_install --option=index-url --set-value=https://${username}:${password}@my-repo.com/pypi/simple/
python setup.py test
```

It works, but I do not like it because the distutils output prints the URL and leaks the passowrd in the CI logs. Is there a better way to so this?

Comment: I believe CI tools (like openshift) has certain ways to register repo and username/password instead of manually writing scripts.

Comment: You have `.pypirc` for storing index credentials (warning: plaintext!)

Comment: @hoefling thank you for the suggestion. That is probably a better option than what I have above. I don't like that I have to write .pypirc in $HOME, but it beats writing the password in the log.